# get_locale() behaving strange in same functions.php file

Tags: localization, plugin-polylang

I'm developing a multi-language web portal for my client - in English and Bengali. Instead of using multisite, I installed Polylang plugin. It's working fine through the website.

For different CSS styles, and different font-sizes I'm loading a separate stylesheet with:

```
function styles_and_scripts(){
   wp_register_style( 'main-style-bangla', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-bangla.css', '', '', 'screen' );

   // load seperate stylesheet for Bangla
   if( get_locale() == 'bn_BD' ) {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style-bangla');
   }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles_and_scripts' );
```

It's working just fine, and loading different CSS when I'm switching to Bengali.

I'm trying the same method for applying filters for Bengali Numerals and Strings etc. with [these functions and filters](http://tareq.wedevs.com/2010/09/translate-wordpress-date-time-comment-number-to-bangla-digit/). So I'm doing something like this in my `functions.php`:

```
if( get_locale() == 'bn_BD' && !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'get_the_time', 'make_bangla_number' );
        add_filter( 'the_date', 'make_bangla_number' );
        add_filter( 'the_time', 'make_bangla_number' );
        add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'make_bangla_number' );

        add_filter( 'get_the_time', 'make_bangla_months' );
        add_filter( 'the_date', 'make_bangla_months' );
        add_filter( 'the_time', 'make_bangla_months' );
        add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'make_bangla_months' );
}
```

But it's not working. I tried to figure out why?

```
$my_locale = get_locale();
var_dump( $my_locale );
```

It's returning "`en_US`" in both the languages. You can see the image below for proof:
[image]

Why the same bit of code in the same `functions.php` file is behaving strange in different cases? I then changed the placement of the code just after the enqueue portion, but it's still not working. :(

### UPDATE

I found a function from Polylang documentation saying:
`<?php pll_current_language($value); ?>` ([Source^](http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/)) will retrieve the current language.

I tried `var_dump(pll_current_language());` it returns nothing.

Then I managed to find the following code:

```
function site_current_language() {
    global $polylang;
    echo $currentLang = pll_current_language('locale');

    return $currentLang;
}
//add_action( 'init', 'site_current_language' );  // it does not print
add_action( 'wp', 'site_current_language' );    // it prints
```

It's working fine, it's echoing the current `$locale`.

But instead of echoing this, if I tried returning, it's returning `boolean false`.

I tried `global $polylang; var_dump($polylang);` without any function or hook, it's showing that it is failing to find the `curlang` within. But if I do the same inside my style/script enqueue fuction, it's getting the current language.

So I suspect there's something related with the proper hook. Note, the hook `init` is failing to echo, but `wp` is echoing. I think we should find a proper hook to get it work.

But how, I don't know.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but usually language files are hooked to the `after_setup_theme` hook. My idea here is, is to add `if( get_locale() == 'bn_BD' && !is_admin() ) { your stuff}` into a function and hooking that function in the `after_setup_theme` hook. I hope this makes some kind of sense

Comment: So I did: `function bangla_things() { if( get_locale() == 'bn_BD' && !is_admin() ) { my stuff } } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bangla_things' );` with no success. Not working. I then tried the raw: `function bangla_things2() { global $locale; $lcl = get_locale(); var_dump($lcl); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bangla_things2' );` I tried both `add_action` and `add_filter`, but failed. :(

Comment: Sorry I could not help. I'm stuck at the same issue as you are. I hope you can manage to get your problem sorted

Comment: closing as this is a polylang question

Answer (score 1):

What did work for me is this:

```
function get_current_language() {
    global $polylang;
    $current_lang = pll_current_language( 'locale' );
    return $current_lang;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'get_current_language', 10 );
```

And then I could use it in other places, like this:

```php
$current_lang = get_current_language( $current_lang );
```

Answer (score -1):

You try this example

```
<?php // outputs a list of languages names ?>
<ul><?php pll_the_languages(); ?></ul>

<?php // outputs a flags list (without languages names) ?>
<ul><?php pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>1,'show_names'=>0)); ?></ul>

<?php // outputs a dropdown list of languages names ?>
<?php pll_the_languages(array('dropdown'=>1));  ?>
```